# Update 2 pictureboxes in parallel

Tags: c#, multithreading, picturebox

I have 2 pictureboxes I would like to update in parallel.

For now I have this:

```
picturebox_1.Refresh();
picturebox_2.Refresh();
```

Within each paint event I have stuff like this:

Picturebox 1:

```
e.Graphics.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.Black);    
e.Graphics.DrawImage(mybitmap1, X, Y); 
e.Graphics.DrawLine(mypen, verticalstart, verticalend); //Draw Vertical
```

Picturebox 2:

```
e.Graphics.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.Black);    
e.Graphics.DrawImage(mybitmap2, X, Y); 
e.Graphics.DrawLine(mypen, verticalstart, verticalend);//Draw Vertical line.
```

Is there an easy way to do this? I'm new to threading etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use the same Paint event handler for both picture boxes?  If I put two picture boxes on a form and set both of them to use the handler shown below, they both display a vertical red line bisecting the box.

```
private void pictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    PictureBox pb = sender as PictureBox;
    if (pb == null) {
        return;
    }
    Pen p = new Pen(Brushes.Red);
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, new Point(pb.Width / 2, 0), new Point(pb.Width / 2, pb.Height));
}
```

edit: extra example

I'd store each bitmap in a dictionary with the picture box as the key as follows:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    private Dictionary<PictureBox, Bitmap> bitmaps = new Dictionary<PictureBox,Bitmap>(); 
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        bitmaps.Add(pictureBox1, mybitmap1);
        bitmaps.Add(pictureBox2, mybitmap2);

    }

    private void pictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
        PictureBox pb = sender as PictureBox;
        if (pb == null) {
            return;
        }
        e.Graphics.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.Black);    
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmaps[pb], X, Y); 
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(mypen, verticalstart, verticalend);//Draw Vertical line.
    }
}
```

Comment: @Matimont - see revised answer for way to keep track of separate bitmaps

Comment: I could use the same event for the 2 picture boxes but the draw would not be in parallel am I right?

Comment: @Matimont - Apparently I misunderstood your question.  No, the above doesn't run in parallel threads. UI updates run on the UI thread, so updating a picturebox from multiple threads isn't possible, other than a worker thread calling back to the UI thread to do the update. Once you do that, the UI thread is going to perform the updates sequentially anyway. If your Paint event does more work than your post implied, you could run that work in a BackgroundWorker and then have the UI update the picturebox. Loading static pics, my example draws both pictureboxes in < 1 ms, not a visible difference.